# Unpack byte string as tuple?

Tags: python

Let's say I have a byte string `b"\x00\x01\x02\x03\x04\x05\x06\x07"` How can I unpack a list of tuples from this? e.g. `[(1, 515), (1029, 1543)]` I want to unpack it like struct would by doing `struct.unpack(">H", sample_bytestring)` but as a list of tuples as shown previously.

Comment: Do you need to *unpack* it as a list-of-tuples, or do you just need to *assign* it with that structure? Is the format always regular (e.g. "pairs of `H`") or would you also need irregular formats (e.g. "pair of `H`s, triple of `H`, `f`, `H`, pair of `H`s")?

Comment: Do you use unpack now? What does your data look like? Why do you need tuples?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by assigning it with that structure, but as far as I'm aware, unpacking it would be the better solution. Basically, I need to use these values to determine the length of some binary data in a file, the first one being the compressed data length and the second one being the decompressed data length, and I need to read the file depending on these values. So, probably unpacking it as a list of tuples, but if you have a better solution you could provide that as well.

Comment: The mini-language used by `unpack` doesn't have any notion of tuples, lists, or any other container. It can only produce a sequence of "primitive" values from a byte string. You'll have to post-process that sequence yourself (using something like the `grouper` recipe in the `itertools` documentation).

Comment: (The closest it has to a "container" is the ability to unpack a series of known length into a `str` value.)

Comment: Could you provide sample code for that if you don't mind?